# where to place DTD inside a package

Tags: java, xml, dtd

I have build a jar which contains a DTD file. I want to use this jar in an external application, in which the DTD file will be used for an XML file.

My question is how can i make my dtd file (which is inside .jar file) accessible from xml?

As we do in other config files of let's say struts hibernate etc, we define DTD in xml which are included in .jar files. I wanna do same in my jar file but not able to figure out the way, Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement an `org.xml.sax.EntityResolver`

```
public class MyResolver implements EntityResolver {

    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
       if (systemId.contains("my.dtd")) {
           InputStream myDtdRes = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/yourcompany/my.dtd");
           return new InputSource(myDtdRes);
       } else {
           return null;
       }
    }
}
```

and use it with your [`DocumentBuilder.setEntityResolver()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#setEntityResolver(org.xml.sax.EntityResolver))

```
 DocumentBuilder docBuilder = ...
 docBuilder.setEntityResolver(new MyResolver());
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code snippets for you...

**Add DTD To JAR**

Use Resolver class for DTD to place DTD to your jar

```
DocumentBuilderFactory myFactory = xmlFactories.newDocumentBuilderFactory();
    myFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    myFactory.setValidating(false);
    DocumentBuilder db = myFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    db.setEntityResolver(new EntityManager());



    public class EntityManager implements EntityResolver
    {
      public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
          /* returns contents of DTD */
      }

    }
```

**Load DTD From JAR**

```
InputStream ins = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("project/mypackage/File.dtd");
```

So, now you have inputstream and you can use it as you like

Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an EntityResolver class for resolving the public or system ID of your DTD to the copy of the DTD that you are placing in the JAR.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = xmlFactories.newDocumentBuilderFactory();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
factory.setValidating(false);
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
documentBuilder.setEntityResolver(new EntityManager());

......

public class EntityManager implements EntityResolver {
  public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
      /* code to check the public or system ID and return contents of DTD */
  }

}
```